# How can I print the overview of a CRM 2011 workflow or dialog process?

Tags: printing, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

Sometimes workflows and dialog processes in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 get a bit long (I mean the number of steps, rather than execution time) and trying to follow them / review them during design-time can be somewhat cumbersome on-screen.

Has anybody found a way to print workflows and dialog process designs to hardcopy? **This is not something that I need to do regularly - nor something for my users (so I don't care how "ugly" the solution is!).**

There *is* a print button on the dialog screen (which brings up a preview screen that can be printed), however when printing it will only render the "header" information in full. The actual workflow/process definition is housed within an iFrame and only a small portion of that is printed on the final output.

I've tried using Internet Explorer Developer Tools to manually force the iFrame (and a few divs inside and outside of it) to be bigger (via the CSS `height` property) - i.e. enough to remove the scrollbars. This looks fine onscreen as promises to work in hardcopy but this has only proven to stop all output rendering in the iFrame at all.

Maybe CSS is the way to go but my efforts have failed and although I have a good handle on CSS it's pretty much guesswork if somethign other than element height is at play here.

I guess I could copy/paste screenshots and jigsaw them together but I'm hoping something more sophisicated exists out there!

---

### **Update:**

I omitted in my original question that I am looking for a cost-free solution if possible. There are already 2 answers that could both be used to achieve my strated goal. I particularly like @AdamV suggestion to use SnagIt as it works a treat. I'd just like to see if there are any **free** options out there before awarding "answer" status first though.

---

### **Update (2):**

Three perfectly viable answers so I'd like to have marked all three as "answers" too. @Daryl gets it as he replied several times and Screen Hunter Pro is cheaper than SnagIt. Despite votes and in spite of my requirement for something free, these are my preferred solutions:

- [Screen Hunter Pro](http://wisdom-soft.com/products/screenhunter_pro.htm) to do a screen grab (US$29.99) as per @Daryl
- SnagIt(approx US$55.00) as per @AdamV
- Copy and paste HTML source as per @Daryl
- Reconstruct from database as per @Daryl

I think the £20 for Screen Hunter Pro is worth avoiding the extra effort for the other options.

Thanks to @AdamV and sorry I can't award answer to you too as I would have liked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a lot more work, and probably prone to being broke by CRM updates, so I would only recommend it as a final option, but you could pull that data from the SQL Database itself via a SSRS Report or any other method you feel more comfortable with.

Comment: +1 for a useful and perfectly viable answer by the sounds of it but I guess I would lose the benefit of the pretty tree structure in the UI (plus, as you mentioned, the effort required to decipher the database structure!)

Comment: Yes, no pretty tree structure UI without a lot of work...  I do use screen hunter to do screen captures.  It's free (for your main monitor only) but is better than a print screen.

Comment: Note that you need Screen Hunter Pro (US$30) to capture scrolling windows

Comment: Never bought the pro version... didn't know you could do a scrolling window screen capture... Nice.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using Techsmith's Snagit to capture all of a scrollable web page as a single screenshot?

Comment: +1 as Techsmith's Snagit does exactly what I asked for, relatively easily - so good call Adam. What I didn't state in my question was that I wanted to do this for free ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick test, using the Developer Tools (F12) and clicking (ctrl + t) to get the source and style, copied the the style and head to a blank html text document, and copied the wfWorkflowDefinitionContainer table to just below the head.

You get the indenting, but not the pictures, but it wouldn't be to hard to do a search and replace to get those as well...

Comment: that sounds like it would do the trick! i'll try it at work tomorrow thanks Daryl.

Comment: This is the cheapest option and with some manual manipulation would probably be perfect. It's not without issues (for example, I still had some scroll problems, not least because of the missing images as you pointed out).